# Theorem numbering in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have a problem with theorem numbering in LaTeX. I can make it number by subsection, e.g

> Theorem 1.2.1

for the first theorem in the second subsection of the first section. But I need it to show me 
only the numbers of the subsection and the theorem, but not the section number, like this:

> Theorem 2.1

I use

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
```

for the numbering.

Comment: Please don't do this. As a frequent reader of mathematical books, I *hate* it when books use this numbering style. If you do this, saying "Theorem 3.2" becomes ambiguous: it can refer to many possible theorems in many places, and does not make complicated material any easier to understand.

Comment: I'm a decade late in responding to kquinn but I really have never found this to be ambiguous. Saying "Theorem 3.2" means the second theorem of the third section of this chapter. To refer to another chapter authors will say "Theorem 3.2 of chapter 1".

Further, this makes it far easier for me to read the theorems as (a) most of the time, chapters are either self contained or have named results from other chapters to refer to, and (b) I'm better at parsing English than I am at parsing sequences of digits.

Comment: @BenKushigian the question asks for theorem numbering which resets with each new *section*, not with each new chapter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Putting the following code in the preamble seems to have the desired effect:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{thm}}
```

I don't understand why you want this particular theorem numbering system, but the code does what you want:
[image: LaTeX output]

Comment: Clever. Note that, while this does what was requested, it depends on the internals of amsthm, so it might be fragile. Also, wouldn't this be confusing to readers since you have "Theorem 1.1" for the first theorem in every subsection?

Comment: @Naaff I'm right with you wondering why the question asker wants to number theorems this way.  I personally would avoid the cross-reference ambiguity that you mention by sticking with the default of section.subsection.theorem, or by numbering theorems consecutively without resetting for the entire document.

Comment: What is this "imageshack" thing doing here?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
```

See these [LaTeX tips](https://web.archive.org/web/20090618120131/http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/tex/theorems.html).

Comment: I've already tried that. That gives me the numbering like this `section_number.theorem_number`, but I need `subsection_number.theorem_number`

Answer (score 1):

There's no *easy* way to do this. The [AMS Theorem Package](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf) only provides a way to control when numbering resets (section, subsection), if it's tied to other environments (corollary, lemma) and number order ("1.1 Theorem" vs. "Theorem 1.1").

Theorem's get their numbering from the `\thesection` or `\thesubsection` command. You can redefine the `\thesubsection` command to get the numbering you want, but that will also affect *everything else* that uses `\thesubsection`.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line in your preamble (or anywhere else before the \newtheorem statement):

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
```

This will reset the numbering command of the thm environment to ignore the section numbers (when numbering theorems) and display only the subsection numbers and theorem numbers.  Section numbers will still be displayed in front of section headings, just not the theorems included within the sections.  So, just as you describe, the first theorem in the second subsection of the first section will be numbered 2.1. 
Alternatives to \arabic include:

- \Roman - produces capital roman numbers, such as II.1
- \roman - produces lower-case roman numbers, such as ii.1
- \Alph - produces capital letters, such as B.1
- \alph - produces lower-case letters, such as b.1

Comment: Won't this affect numbered subsection headings as well?

Comment: Yes, you're right, this will cause both the theorem numberings and the numberings of the subsection headings to ignore section numbers.

Comment: I *think*, although I'm not sure, that you could make the renumbering specific to theorems if you included the \renewcommand line within the \newtheorem environment definition.  But of course, this would require manually re-implementing the \newtheorem environment definition, which may not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

In a slightly less hacky way, you may create a fake counter that is reset with `subsection`, and redefine its `\the` to your liking:

```
\newcounter{fakecnt}[subsection]
\def\thefakecnt{\arabic{subsection}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[fakecnt]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this command for renew command section and subsection and theorem's and ...

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{(\alph{subsection})}‎‎‎
```